# Clarification about AWS S3 endpoints and permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have created a bucket on AWS S3, and created two accounts to access a specific /audio subfolder in the bucket.
The first account has a readonly access, while the second account has a full control access.

The weird thing is that, using the first account, I can access the bucket using the general https://s3.amazonaws.com , while using the second account, I get a location permission error unless I use https://s3.eu-south-1.amazonaws.com .

I cannot guess any relation between users account and endpoints!

EDIT:

I'm using aws-cli and the accounts are on the same AWS account, they are 2 programmatically IAM accesses.

Comment: By "two accounts" do you mean two IAM users (in the same AWS account)? And how are you testing access to the bucket?

Comment: Not 100% related to your question, but Path-Style S2 URLs are deprecated, subject to be discontinued. Virtual-Host URLs should be used instead.

Comment: What is the exact message from the "location permission error" you're observing?

Comment: How are you accessing the files -- direct from a web browser, or via AWS CLI, or perhaps an API call? Please edit your question to provide more details.